# How to get appsettings in unit test project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am able to inject appsettings in a class library. I have a proxy project I use to inject the appsettings then I can inject the proxy class everywhere. However, I can't figure out how to inject my proxy class in a unit test project.

**Appsettings**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

**Startup class**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
    .Configure<EnvironmentSettings.EnvironmentSettings>(Configuration)
    .AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EnvironmentSettings.EnvironmentSettings>>().Value);

    services.AddScoped<Data.ISqlDataController, Data.SqlDataController>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

**EnvironmentSettings class (Proxy)**

This class is in another class library project

```
public class EnvironmentSettings : IEnvironmentSettings
{
    public ConnectionStrings ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is the code that uses EnvironmentSettings**

```
public class SqlDataController : ISqlDataController
{
    private EnvironmentSettings.EnvironmentSettings environmentSettings;

    public SqlDataController(EnvironmentSettings.EnvironmentSettings environmentSettings)
    {
        this.environmentSettings = environmentSettings;
    }

    public string Test()
    {
        return environmentSettings.ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection;
    }
}
```

As you can see I can inject EnvironmentSettings into SqlDataController. EnvironmentSettings is binded in the Startup class.

So I can successfully inject the environmentsettings class in other classes and class libraries but how do I inject it into a unit test project. I don't want to use mocks in this case.

Comment: Why do you believe you need this for a unit test? This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? This sounds more like an integration test.

Comment: @Nkosi I am trying to inject EnvironmentSettings so I can have access to appsettings then call the database. yes you are right this is an integration test.

Comment: If it is a unit test then you should be using a mock. Thats the whole point, you test the class of your intended class and mock anything else it interacts with, else its an integration test. If it is an integration test, you can use anything like Ninject to inject the thing as normal no?

Comment: @AaronGibson The first part of your comment was already answered, and for the second question, the OP is likely using the default IOC container from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: Show us the test code. It is hard to help you without this.

Comment: @zaitsman I have not started the test code yet because I have no idea how to inject the appsettings.

Comment: @Luke101 Ok, show the code for a service that uses those `appsettings` (i don't see a class like that in the code above, neither, there is `EnvironmentSettings`) that you want to test

Comment: @zaitsman np, I edited the question. EnvironmentSettings has all the values of the appsettings which is binded in the Startup class. So, I can inject EnvironmentSettings anywhere except a unit test project.

Comment: So em, what is stopping you from just doing

`IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) // or wherever
            .AddJsonFile("whatever.json")
            .Build();
var settings = config.Get<EnvironmentSettings>();

var target = new SqlDataController(settings);`

Comment: wow..this works for me. Thanks. If you had an answer I'd accept it